# On Debian, how do I make a script that will rerun a Java program after it has stopped or crashed?

Tags: debian, java, startup

I'm running a Java server program that needs to be started with a shell script. The script needs to start the Java program again if it happens to crash or be stopped manually.

I found this script online for it

```
while true
do
   java -jar program.jar
done
```

But that didn't seem to work on my Debian 7 box; it just shows:

```
./start.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

That was just posted as a "Linux" script. How can I make it work in Debian?
Oh yeah and it's important for the program to be started from the script because I need to access its console regularly, unless there's a way for it to not be a script but still let me access its console.

Comment: Perhaps your script has carriage-return line-endings (happens a lot with cut/paste).

Answer (score 4):

That is a perfectly valid script.  It would work fine anywhere.  If you're getting a syntax error, it's because either there was a syntax error introduced when you copy/pasted the script, or as Thomas theorized in the comments your file is using incorrect line terminators.

You can check line terminators using the `od` command, like this:

```
$ od -a foo.sh 
0000000   w   h   i   l   e  sp   t   r   u   e  nl   d   o  nl  sp  sp
0000020  sp   j   a   v   a  sp   -   j   a   r  sp   p   r   o   g   r
0000040   a   m   .   j   a   r  nl   d   o   n   e  nl
0000054
```

You can see here the script on my system is using newlines (that's the `nl` in the output, just after, `t r u e`, for example).  If instead you see just carriage returns:

```
0000000   w   h   i   l   e  sp   t   r   u   e  cr   d   o  cr  sp  sp
```

Or carriage return/newline combinations:

```
0000000   w   h   i   l   e  sp   t   r   u   e  cr  nl   d   o  cr  nl
```

Then you will need to fix that.

Once you get things working, you may want to consider adding a `sleep` command to your script, like this:

```
while true
do
   java -jar program.jar
   sleep 1
done
```

In the event that `program.jar` crashes immediately, the tight loop with no pauses can consume a lot of CPU.  Introducing a small pause largely resolves that particular concern.

Comment: I have no idea what line terminators or anything you've pasted there means

Comment: Well, you can run the commands I suggested, look at the output and see if it matches the descriptions, and leave a comment here with the results, and we'll work from there.

Comment: I used the commands in the comment below and it started woking, thanks for your efforts anyway

Answer (score 1):

larsks' answer is both well written and extensive. Upvote has been given accordingly.

Just a quick note as to:

> Then you will need to fix that.

There are a myriad ways to convert Windows CR to Linux/Unix LF. Here are a few:
Using `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^M$//' infile > outfile
```

Lastly, since you are on Debian, you may have a package called `dos2unix` available. If you install it, it is as simple as:

```
dos2unix myfile
```